# start gui app with startx from console by a non loging user

Tags: command-line, permissions, xorg, root

I have built a htpc with console installation of debian 10 kernel 5.4 and only xorg, my plan is to run kodi/steam client and some dockers. I want to automatically start kodi on system start and for this i don't want to start it with root user, so i created a non login user just to start kodi. I'm not a linux guru and i didnt managed to run with the second user, i have tried several method found in posts but i get ***cannot open display***, the fun fact that if i run with root `xhost +user` or `xclock` i get the same error but `startx kodi` works.

Can someone please let me know how can i give permission for the kodi user to startx and what i've done wrong / not done at all in order to solve the no output display error. I think also the start on boot part will be tricky. Thanks

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The error **"cannot open display"** suggests:

**Either** a display environment is not specified.

Try to specify a display environment. It can be `:0` or `:0:0` or something else. Run the following command to find out:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Then use it before your command like so:

```
env DISPLAY=:0 YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
```

**Or** an X server is not running probably due to unprivileged user provided.

Try editing `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and change `allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody` then save the file and reboot.

Or alternatively run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy` and select `Anybody` then `OK` then reboot.

This should allow any user to run X server.

Comment: ```echo $DISPLAY``` is not showing anything and i get the same error with the command ```env DISPLAY=:0 xclock``` "can't open display", how ```startx kodi``` works i dont understand.

Comment: @Vladimirxro Try editing `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and change `allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody` then reboot and test your command again. This should allow any user to run X server. Or alternatively run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy` and select `Anybody` then `OK` then reboot.