# How to login GUI Desktop using only terminal?

Tags: ssh, login, gui, remote-desktop

Sorry, I'm a Linux newbie and may ask some stupid questions. I use SSH and TeamViewer to control my Ubuntu server in my lab. However, I find that if I remotely restart my server, then I don't know how to log in GUI desktop remotely, and then I cannot launch Teamviewer by SSH terminal.

For details, when I restart my server, my Ubuntu stuck in this step:
[image]
If I'm not right to my server, then I can only connect to my server using SSH terminal. However, I find that I cannot launch TeamViewer using terminal if I haven't login GUI desktop.

[image]

My question:

How to let my server's display showing that I login to some specific user's GUI desktop(e.g. user A, B, C in 1st fig.) only using terminal? That is let my display showing like the following:[image]

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1232609/968501