# How to make 'notify-send' work in a script that is ran by NetworkManager dispatcher?

Tags: bash, 20.04, xubuntu, network-manager, notify-send

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
DISPLAY=:0.0
notify-send "Connecting..."
```

Also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 2
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
DISPLAY=":0"
/usr/bin/notify-send "Connecting..."
exit 0
```

As you can see i have tried setting everything, but it's still not working.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Read `man xhost`. You probably need to `xhost +localhost` in your GUI. This is an X windows answer, IDK about Wayland.

Comment: Set the display environment and use it in the command-line to execute your script  like so `env DISPLAY=:0 bash scriptfile` . See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232620) for how to find out your display environment.